# how to filter an array to get specific columns in two different objects in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder

I need response like this.

```
"result": [ 
{  
  "properties": { 
    "device_id": 15196,
    "device_name": Street Light 1,
    "state" : 1,
    "status": 1,
  }, 
  "geometry":{ 
    "lat":33.7017, 
    "lng": 73.0228 
  } 
},
{  
  "properties": { 
    "device_id": 15196,
    "device_name": Street Light 1,
    "state" : 1,
    "status": 1,
  }, 
  "geometry":{ 
    "lat":33.7017, 
    "lng": 73.0228 
  } 
},
]
```

where my code is below. I just want to sperate two fields 'lat', 'lng' from my whole response. My sql query is correct but i want to create custom response that i mentioned above

```
$get1 = DB::table('device_user')
            ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_user.device_id')
            ->join('components', 'devices.id', '=', 'components.device_id')
            ->select('devices.id as device_id', 'devices.name', 'devices.status', 'components.state', 'components.type', 'devices.lat', 'devices.lng')
            ->where('device_user.user_id', $request->user_id)
            ->where('components.type', $type)
            ->get();
$array = [];
foreach ($get1 as $key => $value) {
array_push($array, ["properties" => $value, "geometry" => $value->lat]);
            }
return $array;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$get1 = DB::table('device_user')
            ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_user.device_id')
            ->join('components', 'devices.id', '=', 'components.device_id')
            ->select('devices.id as device_id', 'devices.name', 'devices.status', 'components.state', 'components.type', 'devices.lat', 'devices.lng')
            ->where('device_user.user_id', $request->user_id)
            ->where('components.type', $type)
            ->get();

$main_array = [];
foreach ($get1 as $key => $value) {

    $main_array[$key]['properties'] = array('device_id' => $value->device_id, 'device_name' =>  $value->device_name, 'state' => $value->state, 'status' => $value->status);
    $main_array[$key]['geometry'] = array('lat' => $value->lat, 'lng' =>  $value->lng);

}
return $main_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times and finally i got this.

```
$get = DB::table('device_user')
            ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'device_user.device_id')
            ->join('components', 'devices.id', '=', 'components.device_id')
            ->select('devices.id as device_id', 'devices.name', 'devices.status', 'components.state', 'components.type', 'devices.lat', 'devices.lng')
            ->where('device_user.user_id', $request->user_id)
            ->where('components.type', $type)
            ->get();
        $finalarray =[];
        foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
            array_push($finalarray, ["properties" => ['device_id' => $value->device_id, 'name' => $value->name, 'status' => $value->status, 'state' => $value->state, 'type' => $value->type, ], "geometry" => ["coordinates" => ['lat' => $value->lat, 'lng' => $value->lng]]]);
        }
```